# PrimeFaces PanelGrid Responsive

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having a problem in PanelGrid of primefaces when it gets responsive

The Inputs are not below the labels.

**PrimeFaces 6.0**

```
<p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                <p:outputLabel value="Pessoa:"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Login:"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Senha:"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Grupos:"/>

                <p:autoComplete id="inptNomeID" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.pessoa}" completeMethod="#{usuarioBean.autoCompletePessoa}"
                    var="pessoa" itemLabel="#{pessoa.nome}" itemValue="#{pessoa}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" forceSelection="true"/>

                <p:inputText id="inptLoginID" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.login}"/>

                <p:password id="inptSenhaID" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.senha}"/>

                <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="inptGrupoID" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.grupos}" label="Cities" multiple="true"
                                  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioBean.listaGrupos}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
</p:panelGrid>
```

See the pictures below

**Not Responsive**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gILi.jpg)

**Responsive ERROR**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYlmh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the outputLabel right before the element it corresponds to. For instance:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Pessoa" />
<p:autoComplete id="inptNomeID" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.pessoa}" completeMethod="#{usuarioBean.autoCompletePessoa}"
                var="pessoa" itemLabel="#{pessoa.nome}" itemValue="#{pessoa}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" forceSelection="true"/>
```

This ensures the label is properly positioned on top of the corresponding input in the mobile responsive view.

For more detail, view the example code at the bottom of this page:
[PrimeFaces Responsive Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/responsive.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That way it really works. I found the form this first form of my form also managed to leave the fields responsive in a correct way.